# Best Practice to call a login dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm building an Android application and that aplication have an open part and some actions that need authentication.

What I do is to when the user click on an action that needs authentication a login dialog is show, the user can login and the login will be valid for 30 minutes.

So I have 3 buttons in an fragment that when clicked check if the user is logged in, an if not calls a login dialog.

The problem is: How can I identify what button was clicked, because when the user click the button and is not authenticated I just create the login dialog and set the setTargetFragment to the caller fragment, that was the same for the 3 buttons.

Is there a way to pass a parameter to the login dialog to identify that?

The code are as following:

When the user click the button:

```
final DialogFragment loginDialog = new LoginDialogFragment();
loginDialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);

btnAprovar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!LoginService.getInstance().isLoggedOn()) {
            loginDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Login");
        }
    }
});
```

And In the dialog:

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_dialog, null);
    final EditText txtUser = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    final EditText txtPwd = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    builder.setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.signin, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    DoLogin dl = new DoLogin();
                    dl.execute(txtUser.getText().toString(), txtPwd.getText().toString());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    LoginDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

private void DoPost(Boolean _result) {
    if (_result.equals(true)) {
        ((PublicacaoDetailFragment) this.getTargetFragment()).onAuthTrue();
    } else {
        ((PublicacaoDetailFragment) this.getTargetFragment()).onAuthFalse();
    }
}
```

What is the best Practice to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to figure out which button caused the dialog to appear?

Comment: yes, so in the callback from the login dialog I can continue with the correct action... Or a better way of doing that login

Comment: Why don't you pass in an extra parameter to your LoginDialogFragment.show method? You can pass in the int resource Id for the button, or an enum, or a String...anything really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend @Rodolfo's answer, you should probably use the decorator/wrapper pattern here.

Instead of extending DialogFragment, in your LoginDialogFragment you should just have an instance variable of a DialogFragment. This way, you can have a method called show(String buttonDescription), for example. Inside your own show(...) method, you can call the show() method of the DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending `DialogFragment` in a class of your own, you have two choices:

- Define a variable (with getter and/or setter) inside your custom Dialog class. In your login button `onClick` method, before calling `show()` of your `Dialog`, call the setter for this variable and pass `v.getId()`. In this case, `v` is the `View` associated with the component that you've added the `OnClickListener`.
- Pass your button `View` id within a `Bundle` to your `DialogFragment`.